# Как правильно организовать подключение к БД из ASP.NET веб-приложения?

Tags: c#, база-данных, asp.net, веб-программирование

Нужно каждый раз при обращении создавать новое подключение? Или надо постоянно держать открытым одно подключение через которое все должны работать? Я сейчас каждый раз, когда мне нужно подключиться к БД создаю новое подключение:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
```

Ну и потом закрываю его. А вот как сделать чтобы на всё приложение было только одно общее подключение? И нужно ли вообще так делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использование одного соединения на все приложение усложняет работу с базой данных в нескольких потоках. Поэтому в большинстве сценариев следует открывать соединение непосредственно перед и закрывать сразу после выполнения запроса к базе данных.

Операции открытия и закрытия физического соединения с базой данных являются затратными, поэтому по умолчанию используется пул соединений, и на этот счет не стоит сильно волноваться. При вызове `SqlConnection.Open()` соединение берется из пула, при вызове `SqlConnection.Close()` возвращается в пул и может быть повторно использовано.

Не знаю специфики задачи, но от себя посоветую обратить внимание на такие инструменты как, например, Entity Framework.